# Troubleshooting my WiFi - can't get an IP-address

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-gio

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Gio (Android 2.3). And I can't get a WiFi connection. My brother has the exact some phone and can get a connection.

When I enable WiFi, it tries to connect to the router. It then says it's trying to get an IP-address. But fails to do so and closes the connection.

When going to `*#*#4636#*#*` and into the WiFi Status menu it tells me the following:

```
WiFi state: On
Network State: connection lost
Supplicant State: DISCONNECTED
RSSI: -200
BSSID: 
SSID: 
Hidden SSID: False
IP-adress: 0.0.0.0
Mac-Address: /censored/
Network ID: -1
Link Speed: 1 Mbps
```

What should I try to fix my WiFi connection?

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you already tried so far?  Can you install ADB (from Android SDK) and try to get the log?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Wi-Fi router is not banning you. Wi-Fi routers have a setting to allow/deny specific MAC Addresses which could be used by your brother (to tease you).

If you are allowed to connect with router, this means DHCP is not working for you. DHCP service automatically assign IPs to devices in network. DHCP server on router could be corrected after reboot. It has assigned IP to your brother's device, after all.

If rebooting router doesn't work, it means that DHCP client in your device is not working properly to obtain IP. Try turning off - on Wi-Fi, restart device. If its not a big matter, you may do factory reset, too.

If it's also not working or you don't want to do factory reset, **Fix IP of device**. On Wi-Fi settings screen, hit menu button and tap `Advanced`. From here, you can fix IP to device after ticking `Use Static IP address`. If you don't know IP addressing, grab your brother's IP and change digit after last dot. Make sure, no other device in network has that IP.

Comment: "DHCP not working" could also mean it has been running out of leases (i.e. it has no free IP it could assign). Besides, I encounter a similiar problem with my HTC Buzz running CM7 from time to time: Wifi goes on, it sees the network(s), tries to connect and obtain an IP -- and suddenly all networks are "out of reach" (according to the Wifi setting's network list; you might want to check that as well). While it's not helping to turn Wifi off/on or airplane on/off, just leaving it alone for 10..30min, it finally connects.

Comment: @Izzy That rarely happens in home networks where router is under own control.

Comment: "rarely" does not mean "never" -- one never knows...